# How to sort an response from my API with two date condition and If I don't have one condition, the data must be at the first index

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting

I need to sort a return from my API according to my StartDate, but I have to create a validation if I don't have FinalDate, the data must appears at my first index.

> 1. StartDate: "2004-06-04"     FinalDate: "2004-12-17"
> 2. StartDate: "1997-08-21"     FinalDate: "1998-02-26"
> 3. StartDate: "1997-08-21"
>          FinalDate: undefined

I tried to sort the StartDate. It's works, but what I do with Final Date

```
 this.servidorService.getDesignacoes(this.nomeacaoId).subscribe(
          (response) => {
            if (response.length > 0) {
              this.movimentos = response.sort((a, b) => (b.StartDate< a.StartDate? -1 : b.StartDate> a.StartDate? 1 : 0));
              this.setMovimento();
            }
          },
```

The problem is, the sort of StartDate works, but If I have two equal StartDate, one with FinalDate and other without FinalDate, the data without Final Date must be in the first place.

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: It isn't working because If I have two equal StartDates the sorting is not working.
The data with no Final Date must be at the first place.
I'm gonna editing the question to be more understandable.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the format of the dates you have. Even though your question shows string-formatted dates, I'll start with the `Javascript Date` object assumption. So, supposing your dates are `Javascript Date` objects, you can use the `Date:getTime()` function to do the comparison.

```js
// Depending on the origin of your array, your previously Date objects
// now can be JSON Date strings, so you need to convert them back to 
// Dates (for example, you maybe is receiving the array from a rest API)
b.StartDate = new Date(b.StartDate);
a.StartDate = new Date(a.StartDate);

// To get the array in descending order, the comparison should be
// (just switch a and b with each other to get ascending order)
b.StartDate.getTime() - a.StartDate.getTime()

// first of all, make sure that both FinalDate dates are falsy or truthy 
// at the same time... in this case, you should do a regular comparison of 
// StartDate. After that, when you know that one of them isn't a falsy,
// you can return -1 or 1, depending on what you want (nulls at the end or
// a the start of the array):
!!a.FinalDate === !!b.FinalDate // => assure that both FinalDates are falsy or both are truthy
  ? b.StartDate.getTime() - a.StartDate.getTime() 
  : !a.FinalDate 
    ? -1
    : 1 // b.FinalDate is null, so it should come First
```

So, if you're using regular `Javascript Date` objects coming from a server (the coercing-to-Date-objects part can be skipped if you're sure the dates are objects instead of strings):

```js
this.servidorService.getDesignacoes(this.nomeacaoId).subscribe((response) => {
  if (response.length > 0) {
    this.movimentos = response.sort((a, b) => {
      b.StartDate = new Date(b.StartDate);
      a.StartDate = new Date(a.StartDate);
      return !!a.FinalDate === !!b.FinalDate
          ? b.StartDate.getTime() - a.StartDate.getTime() 
          : !a.FinalDate ? -1 : 1;
    });
    this.setMovimento();
  }
});
```

#### Using Date string comparison

If you're sure the dates you have are ISO strings or something like that, you
can use `localeCompare()` instead of `getTime()`:

```js
this.servidorService.getDesignacoes(this.nomeacaoId).subscribe((response) => {
  if (response.length > 0) {
    this.movimentos = response.sort((a, b) =>
      !!a.FinalDate === !!b.FinalDate
          ? b.StartDate.localeCompare(a.StartDate)
          : !a.FinalDate ? -1 : 1);
    this.setMovimento();
  }
});
```

#### Using 3rd party Date libraries

If you're using 3rd party libraries, like `momentjs` or `date-fns` you can also use their date comparison provided functions instead of the above string's `localeCompare`.